# How to add new line of text by button?

Tags: java, button, javafx, printwriter, bufferedwriter

I have a public method that adds some text from textfield into .txt file, although it works only once.
I want that button to add new line of text everytime I click the button (so we can change text in textfield and add it to new line...).

```
    try {
        ncw = new PrintWriter("database.txt");
        ncw.write(nctext.getText());
        ncw.close();
    } catch (IOException ae) {
        System.out.println("IO Exception");
    }
}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, the second boolean parameter tells FileWriter if it will append or overwrite

true = append mode

false= overwrite mode

```
FileWriter fw = null;
BufferedWriter bw = null;
PrintWriter out = null;
try{

        fw = new FileWriter("database.txt", true);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        out = new PrintWriter(bw);

                    out.println(nctext.getText());
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();


   } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printstacktrace();}
```

Comment: but that deletes the existing text

Comment: "true" parameter totally works! THX

Comment: if you pass true it will write in append mode

Comment: @ItamarGreen it

Comment: @ItamarGreen Sorry I've just pressed enter accidentally. It should looks like that:

        try {
            ncw = new FileWriter("base.txt", true);
   ncbw = new BufferedWriter(ncw);
   
   ncbw.newLine();
   ncbw.write(nctext.getText());
   ncbw.newLine();
   
   ncbw.close();
   
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("IO Exception");
  }
 }